# Error: ...returned a result with an exception set

Tags: python, arrays, numpy-ndarray, system-error

I was trying to copy an Object, which included a numpy array (which included other Objects(type "Feld")), with copy.deepcopy() and got this error: SystemError: <built-in method **deepcopy** of numpy.ndarray object at 0x0000014EFFF0FA50> returned a result with an exception set.
Can anyone tell me, what I am doing wrong?
I searched the whole internet and did not find an answer..

my try to copy an Object

```
for i in range(0, 1040, 130):
    for j in range(0, 1040, 130):
        board.felder[int(i/130)][int(j/130)] = Feld(i+65, j+65)
board2 = copy.deepcopy(board)
```

class Feld

```
image = pygame.image.load("Images/MissingNo.png")

empty = Figure(image)


class Feld():
def __init__(self, x, y, figure=empty, besetzt=False) -> None:
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.figure = figure
    self.besetzt = besetzt

def reset(self):
    self.figure = empty
    self.besetzt = False

def set(self, figure):
    self.besetzt = True
    self.figure = figure
```

innit of class board

```
def __init__(self, player) -> None:
    self.turn = 0
    self.player = player
    self.moves = []
    self.my_move = []
    self.felder = np.empty((8, 8), dtype=Feld)
    self.schach = -1
```

and this is the error message (the full error is more than 100 lines)

> ... The above exception was the direct cause of the following
> exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\copy.py",
> line 137, in deepcopy
> d = id(x) SystemError:  returned a result with an exception set
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\copy.py",
> line 137, in deepcopy
> d = id(x) SystemError:  returned a result with an exception set
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\Users\Nutzer\Videos\Change\ML\PY\Produkt copy\main.py", line 56,
> in 
> board2 = copy.deepcopy(board)   File "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\copy.py",
> line 172, in deepcopy
> y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)   File "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\copy.py",
> line 271, in _reconstruct
> state = deepcopy(state, memo)   File "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\copy.py",
> line 146, in deepcopy
> y = copier(x, memo)   File "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\copy.py",
> line 231, in _deepcopy_dict
> y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)   File "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\copy.py",
> line 153, in deepcopy
> y = copier(memo) SystemError: <built-in method **deepcopy** of numpy.ndarray object at 0x000001DC183C0510>  returned a result with an
> exception set

Comment: show us what you did, we can't really help without seeing the code (edit your question)

Comment: do  you think this is enough?

Comment: could you also add the full stack trace please?

Comment: I hope this is what you mean. Thank you very much for trying to help me!

Comment: This sounds like a bug in Numpy. It seems to be getting ready to raise an exception, but then returns something other than `NULL` as it is supposed(?) to.

Comment: Thank you! Do you also have any idea how to fix this?